# CRM send text from a customfield to the emailbody

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I've been asked to attach attachments to the email and also bring the "notes" written inside the email. I have copied this code that works with attachment. But how can I change the email description?

Here is the code I am using:

http://www.oak3.org/crm/attach-note-attachments-emails/

Answer (score 0):

In workflow, while creating Email you can set the body/description along with Subject from ‘Set Properties’.

Use the Form assistant in the right side if you want to use Record values.

[image]